# IPsets in FirewallD with Nftables backend

Tags: fedora, firewalld, nftables, ipset, firewalld-zone

I upgraded my server to Fedora 32. Firewalld has switched the backend to Nftables.

My setup is pretty simple. Just HTTP, HTTPS, SSH, SMTP ports open and multiple IPsets (IPv4, IPv6) to block a preset list of IP addresses. Earlier I used to do everything in Iptables with Ipsets but right now I'm trying to upgrade my setup to Nftables and I'm using Firewalld for this.

```
$ firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-service=ssh
$ firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-service=http
$ firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-service=https
$ firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-service=smtp
###
Till here things are fine. firewall-cmd --reload works perfectly.
###
$ firewall-cmd --permanent --new-ipset=blacklist --type=hash:net --option=family=inet
$ firewall-cmd --permanent --new-ipset=blacklist6 --type=hash:net --option=family=inet6
$ firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=drop --add-source=ipset:blacklist
$ firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=drop --add-source=ipset:blacklist6
$ firewall-cmd --permanent --ipset=blacklist --add-entries-from-file=blacklist.txt
$ firewall-cmd --permanent --ipset=blacklist6 --add-entries-from-file=blacklist6.txt
```

The moment I run `firewall-cmd --reload` I see the below error and all the traffic to my server gets blocked except SSH, which is already established. New SSH connection is also blocked.

```
$ firewall-cmd --reload
Error: COMMAND_FAILED: 'python-nftables' failed: internal:0:0-0: Error: No such file or directory

internal:0:0-0: Error: No such file or directory

internal:0:0-0: Error: No such file or directory

internal:0:0-0: Error: No such file or directory

internal:0:0-0: Error: No such file or directory

internal:0:0-0: Error: No such file or directory

internal:0:0-0: Error: No such file or directory

internal:0:0-0: Error: No such file or directory

internal:0:0-0: Error: No such file or directory


JSON blob:
{"nftables": [{"metainfo": {"json_schema_version": 1}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "name": "filter_IN_public"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "name": "filter_IN_public_pre"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "name": "filter_IN_public_log"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "name": "filter_IN_public_deny"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "name": "filter_IN_public_allow"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "name": "filter_IN_public_post"}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "filter_IN_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "filter_IN_public_pre"}}]}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "filter_IN_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "filter_IN_public_log"}}]}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "filter_IN_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "filter_IN_public_deny"}}]}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "filter_IN_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "filter_IN_public_allow"}}]}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "filter_IN_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "filter_IN_public_post"}}]}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "name": "filter_FWDI_public"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "name": "filter_FWDI_public_pre"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "name": "filter_FWDI_public_log"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "name": "filter_FWDI_public_deny"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "name": "filter_FWDI_public_allow"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "name": "filter_FWDI_public_post"}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "filter_FWDI_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "filter_FWDI_public_pre"}}]}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "filter_FWDI_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "filter_FWDI_public_log"}}]}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "filter_FWDI_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "filter_FWDI_public_deny"}}]}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "filter_FWDI_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "filter_FWDI_public_allow"}}]}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "filter_FWDI_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "filter_FWDI_public_post"}}]}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "filter_IN_public", "index": 4, "expr": [{"match": {"left": {"meta": {"key": "l4proto"}}, "op": "==", "right": {"set": ["icmp", "icmpv6"]}}}, {"accept": null}]}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "filter_FWDI_public", "index": 4, "expr": [{"match": {"left": {"meta": {"key": "l4proto"}}, "op": "==", "right": {"set": ["icmp", "icmpv6"]}}}, {"accept": null}]}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "name": "raw_PRE_public"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "name": "raw_PRE_public_pre"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "name": "raw_PRE_public_log"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "name": "raw_PRE_public_deny"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "name": "raw_PRE_public_allow"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "name": "raw_PRE_public_post"}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "raw_PRE_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "raw_PRE_public_pre"}}]}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "raw_PRE_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "raw_PRE_public_log"}}]}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "raw_PRE_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "raw_PRE_public_deny"}}]}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "raw_PRE_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "raw_PRE_public_allow"}}]}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "raw_PRE_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "raw_PRE_public_post"}}]}}}, {"insert": {"rule": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "raw_PREROUTING_ZONES", "expr": [{"match": {"left": {"meta": {"key": "iifname"}}, "op": "==", "right": "eth0"}}, {"goto": {"target": "raw_PRE_public"}}]}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "name": "mangle_PRE_public"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "name": "mangle_PRE_public_pre"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "name": "mangle_PRE_public_log"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "name": "mangle_PRE_public_deny"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "name": "mangle_PRE_public_allow"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "name": "mangle_PRE_public_post"}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "mangle_PRE_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "mangle_PRE_public_pre"}}]}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "mangle_PRE_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "mangle_PRE_public_log"}}]}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "mangle_PRE_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "mangle_PRE_public_deny"}}]}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "mangle_PRE_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "mangle_PRE_public_allow"}}]}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "mangle_PRE_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "mangle_PRE_public_post"}}]}}}, {"insert": {"rule": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "mangle_PREROUTING_ZONES", "expr": [{"match": {"left": {"meta": {"key": "iifname"}}, "op": "==", "right": "eth0"}}, {"goto": {"target": "mangle_PRE_public"}}]}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "ip", "table": "firewalld", "name": "nat_PRE_public"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "ip", "table": "firewalld", "name": "nat_PRE_public_pre"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "ip", "table": "firewalld", "name": "nat_PRE_public_log"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "ip", "table": "firewalld", "name": "nat_PRE_public_deny"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "ip", "table": "firewalld", "name": "nat_PRE_public_allow"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "ip", "table": "firewalld", "name": "nat_PRE_public_post"}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "ip", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "nat_PRE_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "nat_PRE_public_pre"}}]}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "ip", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "nat_PRE_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "nat_PRE_public_log"}}]}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "ip", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "nat_PRE_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "nat_PRE_public_deny"}}]}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "ip", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "nat_PRE_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "nat_PRE_public_allow"}}]}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "ip", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "nat_PRE_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "nat_PRE_public_post"}}]}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "ip6", "table": "firewalld", "name": "nat_PRE_public"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "ip6", "table": "firewalld", "name": "nat_PRE_public_pre"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "ip6", "table": "firewalld", "name": "nat_PRE_public_log"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "ip6", "table": "firewalld", "name": "nat_PRE_public_deny"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "ip6", "table": "firewalld", "name": "nat_PRE_public_allow"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "ip6", "table": "firewalld", "name": "nat_PRE_public_post"}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "ip6", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "nat_PRE_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "nat_PRE_public_pre"}}]}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "ip6", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "nat_PRE_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "nat_PRE_public_log"}}]}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "ip6", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "nat_PRE_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "nat_PRE_public_deny"}}]}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "ip6", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "nat_PRE_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "nat_PRE_public_allow"}}]}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "ip6", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "nat_PRE_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "nat_PRE_public_post"}}]}}}, {"insert": {"rule": {"family": "ip", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "nat_PREROUTING_ZONES", "expr": [{"match": {"left": {"meta": {"key": "iifname"}}, "op": "==", "right": "eth0"}}, {"goto": {"target": "nat_PRE_public"}}]}}}, {"insert": {"rule": {"family": "ip6", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "nat_PREROUTING_ZONES", "expr": [{"match": {"left": {"meta": {"key": "iifname"}}, "op": "==", "right": "eth0"}}, {"goto": {"target": "nat_PRE_public"}}]}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "ip", "table": "firewalld", "name": "nat_POST_public"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "ip", "table": "firewalld", "name": "nat_POST_public_pre"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "ip", "table": "firewalld", "name": "nat_POST_public_log"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "ip", "table": "firewalld", "name": "nat_POST_public_deny"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "ip", "table": "firewalld", "name": "nat_POST_public_allow"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "ip", "table": "firewalld", "name": "nat_POST_public_post"}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "ip", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "nat_POST_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "nat_POST_public_pre"}}]}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "ip", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "nat_POST_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "nat_POST_public_log"}}]}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "ip", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "nat_POST_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "nat_POST_public_deny"}}]}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "ip", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "nat_POST_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "nat_POST_public_allow"}}]}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "ip", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "nat_POST_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "nat_POST_public_post"}}]}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "ip6", "table": "firewalld", "name": "nat_POST_public"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "ip6", "table": "firewalld", "name": "nat_POST_public_pre"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "ip6", "table": "firewalld", "name": "nat_POST_public_log"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "ip6", "table": "firewalld", "name": "nat_POST_public_deny"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "ip6", "table": "firewalld", "name": "nat_POST_public_allow"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "ip6", "table": "firewalld", "name": "nat_POST_public_post"}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "ip6", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "nat_POST_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "nat_POST_public_pre"}}]}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "ip6", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "nat_POST_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "nat_POST_public_log"}}]}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "ip6", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "nat_POST_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "nat_POST_public_deny"}}]}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "ip6", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "nat_POST_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "nat_POST_public_allow"}}]}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "ip6", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "nat_POST_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "nat_POST_public_post"}}]}}}, {"insert": {"rule": {"family": "ip", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "nat_POSTROUTING_ZONES", "expr": [{"match": {"left": {"meta": {"key": "oifname"}}, "op": "==", "right": "eth0"}}, {"goto": {"target": "nat_POST_public"}}]}}}, {"insert": {"rule": {"family": "ip6", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "nat_POSTROUTING_ZONES", "expr": [{"match": {"left": {"meta": {"key": "oifname"}}, "op": "==", "right": "eth0"}}, {"goto": {"target": "nat_POST_public"}}]}}}, {"insert": {"rule": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "filter_INPUT_ZONES", "expr": [{"match": {"left": {"meta": {"key": "iifname"}}, "op": "==", "right": "eth0"}}, {"goto": {"target": "filter_IN_public"}}]}}}, {"insert": {"rule": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "filter_FORWARD_IN_ZONES", "expr": [{"match": {"left": {"meta": {"key": "iifname"}}, "op": "==", "right": "eth0"}}, {"goto": {"target": "filter_FWDI_public"}}]}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "name": "filter_FWDO_public"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "name": "filter_FWDO_public_pre"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "name": "filter_FWDO_public_log"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "name": "filter_FWDO_public_deny"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "name": "filter_FWDO_public_allow"}}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "name": "filter_FWDO_public_post"}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "filter_FWDO_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "filter_FWDO_public_pre"}}]}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "filter_FWDO_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "filter_FWDO_public_log"}}]}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "filter_FWDO_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "filter_FWDO_public_deny"}}]}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "filter_FWDO_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "filter_FWDO_public_allow"}}]}}}, {"add": {"rule": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "filter_FWDO_public", "expr": [{"jump": {"target": "filter_FWDO_public_post"}}]}}}, {"insert": {"rule": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "chain": "filter_FORWARD_OUT_ZONES", "expr": [{"match": {"left": {"meta": {"key": "oifname"}}, "op": "==", "right": "eth0"}}, {"goto": {"target": "filter_FWDO_public"}}]}}}]}
```

I've googled a bit and found that IPset is not required in Nftables since nftables have something called sets. How do I configure Nftables sets using Firewalld? Please guide if I'm going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I ran your commands from a centos8 container (but using kernel 5.6) and can't reproduce it: it accepts the rules on final reload. Of course I created files blacklist.txt and blacklist6.txt . Of note is that --ipset gets translated into native nftables sets. My guess is that you're missing your two files: blacklist.txt and blacklist6.txt . Can you give more informations about them?

Comment: @A.B I actually assumed sharing the list might be against the rules or so but here it is. 

https://pastebin.com/YWSkiYAf
https://pastebin.com/fESa5702

I've created the files with the exact content in these two pastebin.

Comment: Looks like I only have issue with the blacklist.txt file https://pastebin.com/YWSkiYAf The error I get is ```Error: COMMAND_FAILED: 'python-nftables' failed: internal:0:0-0: Error: interval overlaps with an existing one

internal:0:0-0: Error: Could not process rule: File exists``` followed by a big JSON blob.

Comment: It appears you must not add intervals that are included in other intervals: eg: `159.138.64.0/21` and
`159.138.67.0/24`. The errors received from such problem are not helpful, there are different errors depending on how exactly the commands are run, but all appear to be from the same initial problem. Feel free to add an answer, I won't. The relevant information isn't in the question but in comments.

Comment: You might wanna check the version of nftables you're running. Debian- and RHEL-based systems tend to lag behind a bit, and nftables gained a lot of functionality going from versions 0.8x to 0.9x, which I suspect may be the culprit here

Comment: don't use pastebin, it's gone now!